# Meteor error EACCES, permission denied '/var/www/'

Tags: meteor

I am building a meteor app that uses manuel:reactivearray package for making reactive arrays.

I do not know what happened but as i installed the package wrote some sample code and waited for the update i am getting this error:

/home/leocrawf/.meteor/packages/meteor-  tool/.1.1.10.1l2mozl++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20160126-16:57:19.116(-5)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20160126-16:57:19.116(-5)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20160126-16:57:19.371(-5)? (STDERR) Error: EACCES, permission denied '/var/www/

I have done every thing from delete the build folder, delete the meteor folder and added all the packages anew excepting manuel:reactivearray but still the same error. Development is now halted until i get rid of this. Any idea how to remove this problem? I am using meteor 1.2.1.

Comment: Check the file permissions on that folder and it's sub folders (both user and group) using `ls -la` on the command line. The user should map to the current user you are running meteor as, which in this case appears to be `leocrawf`.

Answer (score 2):

Check the file permissions on that folder and it's sub folders (both user and group) using `ls -la` on the command line. The user should map to the current user you are running meteor as, which in this case appears to be `leocrawf`. If you plan on running meteor in /var/www as `leocrawf`, then you would need to run this command to change the file permissions to that user:

```
chown -R leocrawf /var/www
```

Personally I set up explicit users specifically for each instance, so I have a user called `DEV` who uses the `/var/www/DEV` folder to run meteor.

Comment: I tried  chown -R leocrawf /var/www but i got chown: cannot access ‘/var/www’: No such file or directory. Coming to my senses I realized that "/var/www " is making reference to the linux file system. so i checked /var/ for /www/ but it was not found. so i created it a gave the property read/write permissions. the ran the above command again. I then got :
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/www’: Operation not permitted. I then check the meteor terminal and the error was gone. Thanks so much.